# How to implement distrbuted tracing in .net environment with opentelemetry?

Tags: asp.net, rabbitmq, masstransit, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

I have applications:

1. asp.net api
2. asp.net api
3. asp.net with mass transit consumer

And configure tracing on each application with opentelemetry
when I send request from first api to seconnd everything works good, and I have same traceid on each application logs
But when I send message from first api in rabbitmq through masstransit and third application where consumer run consume the message tracing didnt work.
I couldnt found in documentation how to handle this issue.
Could you give me instruction or show in which direction I should serach the solution.

[image]

simple schema.

I try to create distributed tracing between web api application and web application with rabbitmq consumer.

I expect that after I send request to first api and after that first api produce message to rabbitmq and onn another web application consumer consume message I could see in console same traceid from first api

Comment: MassTransit supports Open Telemetry out of the box [video](https://youtu.be/WsTYClGrOVI) [docs](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/observability).